# Handlebars helper: Compile template and keep @root

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I'm using grunt-compile-handlebars to compile my handlebars and I have the problem, that the `@root` object changes after I use

```
[...]
handlebars.compile(template);
template(context.data);
[...]
```

So when my json object is something like

```
{
    "template": "path/to/template",
    "data": {
        "greetings": {...}
    }
 }
```

this is always my `@root` object.

I have something like:

```
var handlebars = require('../../node_modules/grunt-compile-handlebars/node_modules/handlebars')     ;

module.exports = function(context) {

    var template = handlebars.partials[context.template];

    template = handlebars.compile(template);

    return new handlebars.SafeString( template(context.data) );

};
{{helper .}}
```

Now my `@root` object is:

```
"data": {
    "greetings": {...}
}
```

Is there a way I can preserve the `@root` when calling `template(...)`

Note: This is a very simplified example. I know that I also could use `{{>path/to/template .}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/945:

`template(context, {data: {root: options.data.root}})`